# Stop docker in Dockerfile if a script exited

Tags: docker

In my `Dockerfile`, I start a process using CMD:

```
# Start MyProcess
CMD ./my_process.sh >> /log/myprocess.log
```

`my_process.sh` may `exit 0` according to some conditions inside that script. Is there a way to safely stop the container from running/starting? right now, it keeps restarting indefinitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try leveraging restart policies, add below argument during `docker run` -

`docker run --restart on-failure .....`

> **--restart on-failure**
>
> Restart only if the container exits with a non-zero exit status.
>   Optionally, limit the number of restart retries the Docker daemon
>   attempts.

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: is it possible to specify two policies? `unless-stopped` and `on-failure`

Comment: I don't think you can add two policies.